# put extras in tabs

Tags: java, android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhostscreen_tabhost);
            mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);

            tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
            mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState); //after the tab's setup is called, you have to call this or it wont work

            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            Intent intent;
            //set up your tabs here. It's easy to just do seperate activities for each tab, and link them in here.
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tagname1").setIndicator("tab indicator 1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tagname2").setIndicator("tab indicator 2").setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
```

Can i put extras into those tabs, and if it's true, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put extras. Do something like this:

```
  intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("this_is_my_extra", "hello world!");

  spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tagname1").setIndicator( ... );
  spec.setContent(intent);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: Ok it's working, i just read a lot of post saying it was not possible to do it like this, but this work.